# Connection To SQLServer2014 Database suddenly stopped working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sql-server-2014

Hi I have been running a simple C# application and was working fine, until had a power outage and the connection to the remote SQLServer database has stopped working. I have checked the IP address, I have pinged the IP address and it works fine, but for some reason if I try and test connection in the visual studio connection properties I get the error shown in the picture and Have no idea why? Please help.

[image: Screenshot: Error shown]

Comment: check if your SQL service is running

Comment: Can you type the error in the image? Some of us can't read in images very well. Many thanks.

Comment: The error says: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operations timed out)

Answer (score 0):

SQL instance seems to be have stopped

1) Go to Run

2) Type Services.msc

3) Looks for SQL Service "SQL Server(SQLExpress)" and check if it is in stop state

4) start it if it is stopped

5) make sure the startup type is automatic

6) Now try again

Comment: I went and checked the SQL Service but it was started and startup type was also set to automatic. I tried restarting it but it didnt make any difference.